# Filtrar array de objetos

Tags: javascript

Hola buenas tardes compañeros tengo una duda, a ver si alguien me puede echar una manito:
1 - Algún curso de tratamiento de arreglos porque me cuesta entender siempre y saber cuando usar filter, reduce, map, etc para dummies
2 - tengo el siguiente arreglo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y lo que quisiera es crear un arreglo que solo tome en cuenta al momento de eliminar la propiedad Ilart y Descripcion, de manera que el resultado final sea algo como esto:

```
res = [
{Ilart:240, CodForm:cualquiera, Descripcion:Formulario Cambio de Tanque, Evidencia:cualquiera},
{Ilart:240, CodForm:cualquiera, Descripcion:Formularo Vista Previa, Evidencia:cualquiera}
]
```

Si notan solo busco comparar la propiedad Ilart y Descripcion no importa lo demas jeje

Intente lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero no entiendo por que me queda como está quedando

Alguna sugerencia ?

Edit:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tan sencillo como: `array.map( ({ Ilart, Descripcion }) => ({ Ilart, Descripcion }) )`

Comment: oh, muchas gracias amigo por su ayuda no sabia que podia hacer tan sencillo eso

Answer (score 1):

Una de las cosas cool de javascript es que puedes *destruir*/*filtrar* objectos y tomar solamente las cosas que te interesan, por ejemplo:

```
let { Ilart, Descripcion } = {
    Ilart: '240',
    Bar: [1,2,3],
    Descripcion: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit.',
    Foo: 30
};

console.log(Ilart); // Es '240'
console.log(Descripcion); // Es 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit.'
```

Ahora, si quieres solo tomar los valores que te interesan de un arreglo puedes ir uno por uno puedes usar un clásico `for`:

```js
let arr = [
    { Ilart: '240', A: 2, Descripcion: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit.1', B: [1, 2, 3] },
    { Ilart: '241', A: 3, Descripcion: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit.2', B: [1, 2, 3] },
    { Ilart: '242', A: 4, Descripcion: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit.3', B: [1, 2, 3] }
]

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    let { Ilart, Descripcion } = arr[i];

    // en versiones modernas podemos usar arr[i] = {Ilart, Descripcion}
    arr[i] = {
        Ilart: Ilart,
        Descripcion: Descripcion
    };
}
```

Todo este código puede ser más pequeño si lo reducimos a una función `map` regresándonos una *copia* de nuestro arreglo `arr`:

```
arr = arr.map( ({Ilart, Descripcion}) => ({Ilart,Descripcion}) )
```

En esencia, puedes obtener los mismos resultados que un `map` con un `for`.

---

Si requieres deshacerte de duplicados de objetos puedes usar:

```
arr = arr.filter((elem, index) => {
    const firstIndex = arr.findIndex(({ Ilart, Descripcion }) => {
        return Ilart === elem.Ilart && Descripcion === elem.Descripcion
    });
    return firstIndex === index
});
```

Comment: Wow buenisimo amigo, ahora si tengo en mi caso varios con el mismo Ilart y descripcion como puedo al mismo tiempo que selecciono eliminar duplicado se podria ? checa la ultima imagen que subi de mi pregunta. Y por ultimo recomiendas algun curso que aprenda de manera sencilla todo esto ?

Comment: Por lo menos yo se que Set crea un array con elementos unicos pero si yo hiciera un let noDupli = new Set (arr) me genera un arreglo pero de los mismos objetos entonces en ese caso no entiendo muy bien como funciona

Comment: Hay un detalle, los Set funcionan muy bien con `String`, `Number` y cositas, pero con `Object` no hay un estándar para saber cuando un objecto es igual a otro (puedes comprobarlo con `{a: 1} === {a: 1}` o  con `{a: 1} == {a: 1}`).
Por lo que tienes que desacerté de los duplicados a manita, eso queda muy bien para tener su propia pregunta en este foro para que otras personas puedan verlo, pero puedo añadir como un plus a mi respuesta.